# problems library react-native-contacts not working ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-contacts

I was testing an example from the react-native-contacts library in which I leave the link: https://github.com/morenoh149/react-native-contacts/tree/master/example

- git clone https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts.git
- cd react-native-contacts/example
- npm install
- cd ios && pod install && cd ..
- npx react-native run-ios

at the moment of running the example, a view is displayed with the supposed contacts that I have stored in ios but nothing can be displayed.

my problem is that I don't know what can be missing in the example from the same library, in android it works perfect. But the problem is ios in which it is not working.

please help.

[react-native-contacts image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WPdw.png)

Comment: Did you try with DOM Javascript?